# Trigger Change event when the Input value changed programmatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an Input in my form.

```
<input type="text" id="changeProgramatic" onchange="return ChangeValue(this);"/>
```

If I change the value in this textBox (changeProgramatic) using another JavaScript function it won't trigger the change Event.(Note: I'm passing 'this' into the method)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to trigger event in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You are using jQuery, right? Separate JavaScript from HTML.

You can use [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) or [triggerHandler](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/).

```
var $myInput = $('#changeProgramatic').on('change', ChangeValue);

var anotherFunction = function() {
  $myInput.val('Another value');
  $myInput.trigger('change');
};
```

Comment: How can I get this event using jQuery selector?

Comment: I was asking for this
`$(document).bind('mycustomevent', function (e, arg1, arg2, arg3) { /* ... */ });`

Comment: For the benefit of others to simplify this answer, basically just call $(this).trigger('change'); in the function that changes the value of the text input programmatically, where "this" is the text input.

Comment: NOTE: this triggers Jquery event only. Not the browser native `change`

Answer (score 218):

Vanilla JS solution:

```
var el = document.getElementById('changeProgramatic');
el.value = 'New Value'
el.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
```

Note that `dispatchEvent` doesn't work in old IE (see: [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=dispatchevent)). <del>So you should probably only use it on internal websites (not on websites having wide audience)</del>.

So as of 2019 you just might want to make sure your customers/audience don't use Windows XP (yes, some still do in 2019). You might want to use [conditional comments](https://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) to warn customers that you don't support old IE (pre IE 11 in this case), but note that conditional comments only work until IE9 (don't work in IE10). So you might want to use feature detection instead. E.g. you could do an early check for:
`typeof document.body.dispatchEvent === 'function'`.

Comment: any reason why this wouldn't work in the chrome console?

Comment: @ecoe not that I can think of... I guess there might be a problem when stepping (debugging) some other function.

Comment: Turns out I was trying to fire an event of a ReactJS input component. The React event system is an additional layer of abstraction.

Comment: @Sunnyday hm... works fine for me for this example script: https://jsfiddle.net/eccenux/tg9o7wqy/6/ .

Do you mean some custom event? Also do you mean the Edge-Edge (old, built in with Windows 10) or Edge-Edgy (Chromium based)?

Comment: Worked for me with the addition of bubbles: true... `el.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', { 'bubbles': true }));`

Comment: This should also trigger `change`, when old and new value are the same, i.e. unchanged.

Comment: Might be helpful to know you might be triggering the wrong event. In my case, I was triggering a `change` event when the input was being watched for an `input` event.

Answer (score 19):

If someone is using react, following will be useful:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62111884/1015678

```
const valueSetter = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(this.textInputRef, 'value').set;
const prototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(this.textInputRef);
const prototypeValueSetter = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(prototype, 'value').set;
if (valueSetter && valueSetter !== prototypeValueSetter) {
    prototypeValueSetter.call(this.textInputRef, 'new value');
} else {
    valueSetter.call(this.textInputRef, 'new value');
}
this.textInputRef.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true }));
```

Comment: This isn't *only* useful for react. The other answers are missing the `bubbles: true`, and this has that key part.

Comment: "{ bubbles: true }" saved me hours of further digging, definitely worth trying for anyone having similar issues

Answer (score 12):

When changing the value programmatically, you need to call the `input` event, not `change` event.

[Note: The input event is fired every time the value of the element changes. This is unlike the change event, which only fires when the value is committed, such as by pressing the enter key, selecting a value from a list of options, and the like.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event)

```
const el = document.getElementById('changeProgramatic');
el.value = 'New Value'
el.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { 'bubbles': true }));
```