# TypeError : Is Event handler 'change'. working correctly?

Tags: javascript, dom

I am unit testing the following method :

```
const initImageUpload = () => {
  const input = document.querySelector('.file-input');
  const fileName = document.querySelector('.file-name');
  if (input) {
    input.addEventListener('change', () => {
      fileName.classList.remove('is-invisible');
    });
  }
};
```

However when I trigger .change() I get an error :

```
let inputImage = document.querySelector('.file-input');
let inputImageFileName = document.querySelector('.file-name');

// WHEN
inputImage.change();
await Promise.resolve().then(); // wait two cycles of the PromiseJobs queue
// THEN
console.log('IMAGE FILENAME: ', inputImageFileName.outerHTML);

**TypeError: inputImage.change is not a function**
```

where am I wrong ? is change() on input field working or not ?

thanks for feedback

Comment: maybe problem with selector "inputImage", what inside, can you share all code?

Comment: You can't call `change` to trigger a change event, the method doesn't exist in elements.

Comment: @Teemu.. Thanks ... It should be triggered by simulating an input in my test I guess

Comment: This might help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent

Comment: Triggering events in the modern browser's way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36084475/3741589 or with support of older browsers https://stackoverflow.com/a/2490876/3741589

Comment: @Quasimodo's clone ... Thanks you're right ... your linked post gave me the solution !

Comment: Should be closed as duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript I cannot revote to close since I pointed to another duplicate and retracted that one. This one is the better Q/A.

Answer (score 0):

as per comment link ( duplicated )

Vanilla JS solution:

```
var el = document.getElementById('changeProgramatic');
el.value='New Value'
el.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
```