# how to trigger a change event on a selectwhen changing it's value programmatically

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

so, using pure Javascript and DOM:

```
const select = document.querySelector('#my-select')

select.addEventListener('change', function(){
  console.log('changed', this.value)
})

select.value = 'some value from an existing option'
// this changes the select correctly, but it doesn't trigger the event
```

Is there any way to correctly do this, without jQuery?

Comment: force triggering the change event: `select.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));` as seen on the stack: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16250464/trigger-change-event-when-the-input-value-changed-programmatically (vanilla JS solution)

Comment: also useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856513/how-can-i-trigger-an-onchange-event-manually

Comment: GrafiCode, can you put it in form of an answer so i can accept it and close this question please?

Comment: Don't worry about that, as a matter of fact I did not answer it

Comment: it's just so this question doesn't stay open, please

Comment: @André allright then

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I programmatically force an onchange event on an input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136617/how-do-i-programmatically-force-an-onchange-event-on-an-input)

Answer (score 0):

You can force triggering the change event this way:

```
select.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
```