# How to trigger input form validation at 3rd party site via browser DevTools?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to complete 3rd party form with several text inputs and selectors. Site is written using AngularJS 1.4.9. I prepared simple script to populate values in all required fields.

```
dict = {'input1' : 'value1', 'input2' : 'value2'};
for (field in dict) {document.getElementById(field).value = dict[field]};
```

Problem is that such approach doesn't trigger fields validation as no events were fired. Hense 'submit' button remains inactive. Is there a way to trigger `change` or other event from a script? Or probably there is even better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer here: [Trigger Change event when the Input value changed programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16250464/trigger-change-event-when-the-input-value-changed-programmatically)

```
for (field in dict) {
  el = document.getElementById(field);
  el.value = dict[field];
  el.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'))};
```