# Node puppeteer how to type into a list of input elements

Tags: node.js, automation, puppeteer

I'm trying to recreate this bot I made in python to go through a Google form, fill it out and submit. The way in python was to collect all the input tags into a list, then just loop over then with another list to type in all the text I wanted. But in puppeteer I cant seem to do the same.

```
const run = async () => {

const width = 1000
const height = 1000

const browser = await pup.launch({
    headless: false,
    defaultViewport: {
        width,
        height
    }
});

const [page] = await browser.pages();
await page.goto('https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdJfQRqH7JmtzrkwPId2Vth3pteB90KYNnqeYpz_hO6i4_ug/viewform')

const input = await page.waitForSelector('input.whs0nd.zHQkBf');
await inn.type('hello')
await page.$$eval('input.whsOnd.zHQkBf', inputs => inputs.forEach(x => {
    x.type('hello')
}))

}

run()
```

In the line with waitForSelector I am trying to wait till the first input element is visible then type into that but I just keep getting a timeout error as seen below.

```
node app.js
C:\Users\carjames\OneDrive - Cisco\Documents\Code\puppeteer 
TUT\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\DOMWorld.js:528
        const timeoutError = new Errors_js_1.TimeoutError(`waiting for ${options.title} 
failed: timeout ${options.timeout}ms exceeded`);
                             ^

TimeoutError: waiting for selector `input.whs0nd.zHQkBf` failed: timeout 30000ms exceeded
    at new WaitTask (C:\Users\carjames\OneDrive - Cisco\Documents\Code\puppeteer 
TUT\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\DOMWorld.js:528:34)
    at DOMWorld.waitForSelectorInPage (C:\Users\carjames\OneDrive - 
Cisco\Documents\Code\puppeteer 
TUT\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\DOMWorld.js:432:26)        
    at Object.internalHandler.waitFor (C:\Users\carjames\OneDrive - 
Cisco\Documents\Code\puppeteer 
TUT\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\QueryHandler.js:31:77)     
    at DOMWorld.waitForSelector (C:\Users\carjames\OneDrive - Cisco\Documents\Code\puppeteer 
TUT\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\DOMWorld.js:323:29)
    at Frame.waitForSelector (C:\Users\carjames\OneDrive - Cisco\Documents\Code\puppeteer 
TUT\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\FrameManager.js:942:51)
    at Page.waitForSelector (C:\Users\carjames\OneDrive - Cisco\Documents\Code\puppeteer 
TUT\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\Page.js:2359:33)
    at run (C:\Users\carjames\OneDrive - Cisco\Documents\Code\puppeteer TUT\app.js:30:28)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

Node.js v17.6.0
```

I also tried to loop through all the input elements in the commented out lines. That also didn't work. I just kept getting x.type is not a function. As seen below.

```
node app.js
C:\Users\carjames\OneDrive - Cisco\Documents\Code\puppeteer 
TUT\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\ExecutionContext.js:221
        throw new Error('Evaluation failed: ' + 
helper_js_1.helper.getExceptionMessage(exceptionDetails));
              ^

Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: x.type is not a function
    at __puppeteer_evaluation_script__:2:11
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at __puppeteer_evaluation_script__:1:19
    at ExecutionContext._evaluateInternal (C:\Users\carjames\OneDrive - 
Cisco\Documents\Code\puppeteer 
TUT\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\ExecutionContext.js:221:19)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async ExecutionContext.evaluate (C:\Users\carjames\OneDrive - 
Cisco\Documents\Code\puppeteer 
TUT\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\ExecutionContext.js:110:16)
    at async JSHandle.evaluate (C:\Users\carjames\OneDrive - Cisco\Documents\Code\puppeteer 
TUT\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\JSHandle.js:103:16)
    at async ElementHandle.$$eval (C:\Users\carjames\OneDrive - Cisco\Documents\Code\puppeteer 
TUT\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\JSHandle.js:844:24)
    at async DOMWorld.$$eval (C:\Users\carjames\OneDrive - Cisco\Documents\Code\puppeteer 
TUT\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\DOMWorld.js:124:23)
    at async run (C:\Users\carjames\OneDrive - Cisco\Documents\Code\puppeteer TUT\app.js:32:5)

Node.js v17.6.0
```

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

This is a common Puppeteer mistake, assuming that the callback to `eval` runs in Puppeteer/Node context, when the code is actually executing the code in the browser console. As the error tells you, `HTMLElement.type` is not a browser method. That's a Puppeteer/Node ElementHandle method.

Your options are:

1. Select the elements in Puppeteer as ElementHandles using `page.$$(...)`, then loop over them and call `handle.type("hello")` on each.
2. Run an `evaluate` or `eval` callback and use native browser code to fill out the inputs, e.g. `x.value = "hello"`, and optionally trigger event handler(s) with `x.dispatchEvent(new Event("change"))`.

   After seeing the Google form, it turns out this second method won't work, probably because the events aren't trusted (although I didn't research it deeply). That leaves option #1.

As an aside, `inn.type('hello')` doesn't seem like it'll work since `inn` was never defined and `input.whs0nd.zHQkBf` should be `input.whsOnd.zHQkBf` (notice O instead of 0), so I suspect this isn't your actual code.

Comment: So using the page$$ method worked for me. Thank you, but I can't seem to get the eval callback to work. I changed my x.type to x.value = 'hello' but nothing happens. @ggorlen

Comment: The Google drive file doesn't exist for me, so we should agree on a reproducible piece of HTML/JS that I can run and play with to figure out what the problem might be. That code works on the typical HTML input I tested it on to change the value, but it won't trigger any events, which need to be [fired manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16250464/trigger-change-event-when-the-input-value-changed-programmatically). Also, if you have it working with `$$` and a loop entirely within Puppeteer, why not use that approach?

Comment: I dont know why the form isnt working for you its still up
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdJf-QRqH7JmtzrkwPId2Vth3pteB90KYNnqeYpz_hO6i4_ug/viewform?fbzx=8310137457376939679

Comment: And I'm just trying to learn puppeteer really I already made the program I needed in python.

Comment: That's a different link than the one in your snippet above, but the new link works for me. I'll take another look at this if I have time.

Comment: I took a look at it -- there are a couple of issues. One is that the textarea selector for a couple of fields wasn't being used, but the bigger issue is that without trusted events (I'm guessing), the forms don't trigger validation, even after dispatching an event. I'd have to play around with it a bit more, but for now I'd stick to the `.type()` method so you can be sure the events are trusted.