# finding sum of prefilled fields with jquery

Tags: jquery, sum

I am trying to find the sum of 2 fields that were both pre filled earlier in the form based on conditionals in another script, so there is no direct input of these fields. The following code works if I directly change the value in those fields, but not if they have been previously filled.

```js
$(document).on('change keyup blur', '#member_type', function () {
  var val = $('#member_type').val();
  if ($('#member_type').val() == 'junior') var result = 10;
  else if (($('#member_type').val() == 'senior', 'master')) var result = 15;
  $('#scDues').val(result);
  calcTotal();
});

$(document).on('change keyup blur', '#num_boats', function () {
  if ($('#num_boats').val() == '0') var result = 0;
  else if ($('#num_boats').val() == '1') var result = 10;
  else if ($('#num_boats').val() == '2') var result = 20;
  else if ($('#num_boats').val() == '3') var result = 30;
  $('#scBoatFee').val(result);
  calcTotal();
});

function calcTotal() {
  var sum = 0;
  $('.fee').each(function () {
    sum += +$(this).val();
  });
  $('#totalFee').val(sum);
}
$('.fee').keyup(function () {
  var sum = 0;
  $('.fee').each(function () {
    sum += Number($(this).val());
  });
  $('#totalFee').val(sum);
  calcTotal();
});

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#scDues, #scBoatFee').change(function () {
    var value1 = parseFloat($('#scDues').val()) || 0;
    var value2 = parseFloat($('#scBoatFee').val()) || 0;
    $('#scTotal').val(value1 + value2);
  });
  calcTotal();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span>Member Type</span>
<select name="member_type" id="member_type">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="junior">Junior</option>
  <option value="senior">Senior</option>
  <option value="master">Master</option>
</select>
<br><br>

<span>Number Boats</span>
<select name="num_boats" id="num_boats">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<br><br>

<span>SC Dues</span>
<input type="text" value="" name="scDues" id="scDues" maxlength="12" />
<br><br>
<span>Boat Fee</span>
<input type="text" value="" name="scBoatFee" id="scBoatFee" maxlength="12" />
<br><br>
<span>Total SC</span>
<input type="text" value="" name="scTotal" id="scTotal" />
```

How can I make this work?

I tried removing the whole line with the .change(function () , but then it doesn’t work at all.

Comment: You have an incorrect type of quote before `#scDues`.

Comment: Also before `#scTotal`, and it's missing the end quote.

Comment: I can't see any reason why this would have different results depending on whether the fields have been previously filled. Add the code that fills them.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: I edited my original post with the snippet, but it is not working the way it is on the live site. On the site, the 'scDues' and 'scBoatFees' are filled in when Member Type and Number of Boats is filled. I'm not sure why it's not working here. It is just 'scTotal' that is not being filled.

Comment: Setting input values programmatically does not trigger a _change_ event

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trigger Change event when the Input value changed programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16250464/trigger-change-event-when-the-input-value-changed-programmatically)

Comment: I added calcTotal, plus another section of the script, so now it is working as on the live site. I now need scTotal to automatically sum scDues and scBoatFee. All 3 of those fields will be hidden and past onto another form.

Comment: Phil - I looked at the page you suggested, but am not seeing how it applies. I don’t have a lot of experience with JavaScript. Can you be more specific? I have 2 fields that will be filled. And need the 3rd field to show the sum.

Comment: Where are `id="totalFee"` and `class="fee"` in the snippet? `calcTotal()` uses them, but they don't exist.

Comment: We were able to find an alternative way to get what we needed, but thank you for looking.